# Need to create dynamic text for menus with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, menu, getelementbyid

I need to assign dynamic text values to certain elements which can then be placed throughout a site I'm working on, as it will need to be localized later at some point.

I was hoping creating a list of them in JS like below-

```
document.getElementsById('title').innerHTML="Title1 Text";
document.getElementsById('title2').innerHTML="Title2 Text";
```

But of course I want to have multiple copies of the `title`, `title2` divs throughout, which won't work because of the `getElementsById` structure. Does anyone have any other suggestions or workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use classes instead of ID's, something like

```
<p class="introText">Title1 Text</p>
<p class="closingText">Title2 Text</p>
```

And instead of affecting just one you could affect all of them and should you want to target just one, you can add an ID to that one.

```
<p class="introText" id="topIntro">Title1 Text</p>
<p class="closingText">Title2 Text</p>
<p class="introText">Title1 Text (again)</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use classes instead of id. but JavaScript doesn't have a getElementsByClass() function by default so unless you want to use something like JQuery, you would have to define the function yourself.

```
document.getElementsByClass = function(class){
   var itemsfound = new Array;
   var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
   for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
      if(elements[i].className == class){
         itemsfound.push(elements[i]);
      }
   }
   return itemsfound;
}
```

this will return an array of elements with the specified class. then you can use the following code as needed.

```
document.getElementsByClass('class'); // gives an array of elements of given class
document.getElementsByClass('class')[0]; // selects first element in array with given class
```

but if you were to use JQuery, it's as simple as doing this:

```
$('.title').html("Title 1 Text");
$('.title2').html("Title 2 Text");
```

hope this helps in some way. cheers

Comment: What about `document.getElementsByClassName`? That should get elements by class.

Comment: it is only natively supported by the most recent versions of Firefox, Safari, Opera and IE9. it's not going to work in IE8 or lower

Comment: I see. But you should probably check for a native version first, before redefining the function.
Edit: It seems like `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` are supported by IE8. You should check for that also.

Comment: ah yes. definitely. if you aren't supporting IE7 document.querySelector will definitely be much better than redefining the function. cheers!